# UI becoming unresponsive for kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am consistently facing issue with kendo grid for following scenario.

I have a kendo grid with 18 columns. User can select multiple rows. Number of rows are mostly more than 10000.

To get selected rows, I am using `grid.select()`. To extract contents from the row, I am using `grid.dataItem(row)`.

Following is the code snippet.

```
            var listofselectedrows = grid.select();
            listofselectedrows.each(function (index, row) {
            var currentDataRow = grid.dataItem(row);
           });
```

Whenever number of selected rows are more. UI is becoming unresponsive. 
I debugged the code. `grid.dataItem(row)` is taking a lot to execute which makes web page unresponsive.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: Please post your grid code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Number of rows are mostly more than 10000", do you want to display 10000 row on 1 page? mostly i use paging with server/client filtering and show for example 20 row per page which mean less data from server, faster, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look into their source, `dataItem` function using regex `/k-grouping-row|k-detail-row|k-group-footer/` looping throung all row element to get the row index. I believe using data source `getByUid` will be faster than using `dataItem` function.

Change your code to be like this

```
$.each(listofselectedrows, function (index, row) {
    var uid = $(row).data("uid");
    var currentData = grid.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Performance Tunning**

When binding to large data sets or when using large page sizes, reducing active in-memory DOM objects is important for performance. Kendo Grid provides built-in UI virtualization for highly optimized binding to large data sets. Enabling UI virtualization is done via simple configuration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
         scrollable: {
             virtual: true
         }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution. But doesn't seems to be working for large number of data rows. UI stll becomes unresponsive at 'grid.dataItem(row);'

Comment: just a suggestion. try disabling the layout while you load the data nad once that is done enable it

Answer (score 0):

Use paging:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },       
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true        
    },
    height: 250,    
    pageable: true,
    selectable: "row multiple",
    columns: [
        "OrderID",
        "Freight",        
        "ShipName",                            
        "ShipCity"        
    ],   
});
```

Comment: In need to perform various synchronization, hence can;t use paging here.